# PHP Select command using 2 tables, result output needed in 1 json array

Tags: php, json

My command is

```
$stmt2 = "select rowsno , comid , sno , tag_from FROM tasktag where COMID='$COMID' and  TAG_FROM = '$TAGFROM'";
```

I want to fetch 1 more value in it but from a different table using the "sno" from the above select command

I wish to fetch `LATEST_ACTIVITY_NO from admtask where sno = sno;`

I want this inside stmt2 command only, because it's returning a JSON array like this -

```
[
  {
    "ROWSNO": "2224",
    "COMID": "54578",
    "SNO": "31598",
    "TAG_FROM": "SAURABH"
  }
]
```

and I wish to include `LATEST_ACTIVITY_NO` in it. How can I do it?

Comment: use `JOIN`, or `UNION` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: get data using JOIN and then encode the result into JSON using json_encode().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try SQL join ?

```
<?php

$stmt2 = "select t.rowsno , t.comid , t.sno , t.tag_from, a.LATEST_ACTIVITY_NO FROM tasktag t JOIN admtask a ON a.sno = t.sno where COMID='$COMID' and  TAG_FROM = '$TAGFROM'";
```

Answer (score -2):

You could try this:- 
`$query = mysql_query($stmt2);while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query){$sno = $result['sno'];};`
 Use this $sno variable in your next query

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Keep in mind that `mysql_query` has been deprecated for long time, and that a `JOIN` helps to avoid unneccessary queries